# alignment arrows do not appear in relative layout of my android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

i'm new to android and android studio and i'm trying to build a relative layout.
when i choose a relative layout and try to put a for example button inside the layout it sticks to the top left corner of the screen, and the arrows for aligning the element do not appear on the screen and all choosen elements stick together at the top left corner of the screen.

how do you think i can fix the problem??

[image: here is the screen shot from my android studio]

Comment: "the arrows for aligning the element" - do you mean the constraints in constraint layout?

Comment: No,from the tutorial video i saw when you want to drop a for example button to the relativelayout some arrows appear and you can place element wherever you want but in my android studio all elements go to the left top corner and i can not move them with mouse by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the picture, you cannot "align" elements in design editor using RelativeLayout.

Look, you are probably talking about ConstraintLayout.
With ConstraintLayout you can align elements and constrain elements where you need.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout Check out this tutorial.

And also, currently not many people use RelativeLayout as it a little bit complex, has more performance issues than ConstraintLayout.